# Mixing two tables that are interconnected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `address` WHERE ...some requirements...";
```

Among the results $sql has a column called addressid.

Then I iterate through all addressid and execute

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE ...some other requirements... AND addressid = $currentaddressid";
```

I choose * because I use several columns of each so this needs to be taken into account. The result is like

```
$valueone = $sql_assoc_array['name'];
$valuetwo = $sql2_assoc_array['nameproduct'];
```

It looks currently like this:

```
execute $sql
while ($sql is being fetched)
{
  execute $sql2 with addressid
  while ($sql2 is being fetched)
  {
    do stuff
  }
}
```

How can I mix both into one command and give the processing necessary to mysql so the results of $sql2 come immediately?

Comment: why you are not using JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner join between address id of both the tables.

SELECT * from table1 a inner join table2 b where a.addressid=b.addressid.

Comment: That helped. I found the some column names to be duplicate in the result(f.i. id). Is there a way to rename them so I have unique column names in the result?